# Writing stack trace to log file only when exception thrown

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I want to write the stack trace only when I have exceptions, currently I do it like this

```
 layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring} | ${stacktrace}"
```

So I always get it in my log file.

EDIT:

I use this layout for all my logging, so when I dont have any exceptions I also get the stack trace.But I need it only when i have some exception

when I have an exception I have following output, and it what I need

```
2011-07-01 22:59:02.3782|Debug|fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown. | AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly => AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly => Program.Main
```

But without exception :

```
2011-07-01 22:57:26.7117|Trace|fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  | AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly => AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly => Program.Main
```

But I want only

```
2011-07-01 22:57:26.7117|Trace|fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Need ideas how to do so...

Comment: Would you expect to have the stack trace otherwise?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Give us some context?

Comment: @Adrian,Added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in NLog you can use different levels Warn, Error Info etc. You can also log the exceptions with ErrorException, WarnException, InfoException. IE

```
logger.Error("This is an error message");
```

If you want to show the exception then use the following.

```
logger.ErrorException("This is an error with an Exception", e);
```

Update :

```
<target name="Errors" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/ErrorLog.txt" layout="${longdate} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"/>
```

Remove {stacktrace}

Update :

```
Exception e = new Exception();
e.StackTrace // <= The exception holds the stack trace
```

You will get the stacktrace from the exception.

Comment: @Jetho , but I dont want to get the stack trace when I dont have the exception

Comment: If you use Error, instead of ErrorException you wont get the Exception stack trace.

Comment: Still I get it look : 2011-07-01 23:29:29.4367|Debug|fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  | AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly => AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly => Program.Main

Comment: But then when I throw an exceptions I will not log them , but when I have an exceptions I need the stack trace

Comment: The Exception holds the stacktrace. View Example above.

Answer (score 13):

you can use the following layout:

```
${longdate}|${level}|${message} ${onexception:${exception:format=tostring} | ${stacktrace}}
```